# Apostrophe CMS + apostrophe-external-notifications: How to implement support for a new event

Tags: apostrophe, apostrophe-cms

I want to send Slack notifications from my CMS on every 'Submit' event. I successfully got the existing events to fire off in Slack but when I included the following code in the node modules package for apostrophe-external-notifications as follows, I do not receive any notifications.

```
     self.notifyOn('apostrophe-workflow:afterSubmit', (req, submit) =>
    ['{user} submitted the {type} {title} which has these tags: {string}.', submit.from, submit.from, submit.from.tags]
  );
```

Comment: You might want to follow this PR I'm working on to add this event. https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-workflow/pull/304

Comment: Thank you for that. Is it possible to get the whole body object back with the afterSubmit event? The template strings are just returning back Undefined and Unknown, it would be helpful to use the information from the page being submitted.

Comment: You have the document's ID from the new event payload as `_docId`. With that you can request the full document on the project level. Feel free to ask project-specific questions (within reason) in the public chat: https://chat.apostrophecms.org/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`afterSubmit` is not a server event that apostrophe-workflow emits at the moment. There's only a browser event, `workflowSubmitted`, from that action.

**Update 2020-03-05:** This event was added as of `apostrophe-workflow@2.32.0`.

Comment: I'm going to see about adding this event to the module and will update this.